# How to calc $\log1+\log2+\log3+\log4+...+\log N$?

Tags: calculus, summation

How to calculate $\log1+\log2+\log3+\log4+...+\log N= log(N!)$? Someone told me that it's equal to $N\log N,$ but I have no idea why.

Comment: See *Stirling's approximation*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation . More exact: $ \approx n \log(n) - n $.

Comment: It's not equal, only asymptotically equal.

Comment: @Oleg567 can you give more details or proof,thank you.

Comment: There is enough info by wiki link (above), parts **Derivation**, **An alternative derivation**.

Answer (score 5):

$$x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$ so that

$$\log(x-1)\le\log\lfloor x\rfloor\le\log x$$

and

$$\int_0^n\log x\,dx<\sum_{k=1}^n\log k<\int_{1}^{n+1}\log x\,dx.$$

Hence

$$n\log n-n<\log n!<(n+1)\log(n+1)-n.$$

For instance, with $n=100$,

$$360.5170185988\cdots<363.7393755555\cdots<366.1271722009\cdots$$

---

A better approximation is given by the famous Stirling's formula,

$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n,$$
or

$$\log n!=n\log n-n+\frac12\log n+\frac12\log2\pi.$$

For $n=100$,

$$363.7385422250\cdots$$

Comment: How did you get this: $$\int_0^n\log x\,dx<\sum_{k=1}^n\log k$$? I think I'm missing something...

Answer (score 3):

A small $caveat$: "someone" is wrong: try, for example, with $N=2$; then

$$2\log 2=\log 2^2,$$

while

$$\log1+\log 2=\log 2!=\log 2.$$

For more details on the relationship between the 2 logarithms, I refer to the comments under the OP.

Comment: thanks,but there is another question, how could I type math symbol in this site, such as pi,lim etc.

Comment: you are welcome: for a quick introduction to the LaTeX typesetting please have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. On asking please read the content in http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: yeah,$$\max _{ 1 }{1000 \iiint _{  a}^{b  }{c  }  } $$

Comment: exactly! Please, do not forget to flag+upvote answers you found useful. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: I'm new to this site, I have not enough reputation to upvode and flag.

Answer (score 3):

This holds true only for large values of N and Asymptotic notation. i.e. $log(N!)=O(NlogN).$

Comment: Why does it hold true for Asymptotic notation and large values if not for others?

Comment: Per 'Stirling's approximation` log(n!) = nlogn -n + O(logn), so for larger numbers the above approximation holds true.

Answer (score 0):

The integral

$$\int_1^{N}\log(x) \; dx= N\log N - N +1$$

is a good approximation.

For $N=100$, the sum equals $361.3197940$ while the above expression gives $361.5170185.$

Comment: $\log 100!=363.73937555\cdots$.